# How to stop browser open a pdf file?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am building a website and there is an embed `iframe` on the page. I found that when users drop a `pdf` file over the `iframe`. The browser will close my website and load the pdf. How can I stop browser rendering the pdf file? I know the drop event I can use but this case happens in the `iframe`. Is there a way for me to handle drop over iframe? My `iframe` is loading a url which is not the same origin as the parent window.

I don't have control on the `iframe` I am embedded. What I want is if the `iframe` doesn't handle drop event then I disable the drop otherwise let `iframe` to handle it.

Comment: Not sure what you need in iframe, maybe `pointer-events: none` css class on iframe

Comment: is the user supposed to be able to drop something into the iframe? if not - why not listen for a drag-n-hold event over the parent window and hide/disable child iframe

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to an iframe, it just is what browsers do when you drag a pdf onto them - or most other files they can open, as far as I know. I wouldn't worry about it. If it's fine for every other site, it's probably fine on yours. If a user has complained, just explain it's the browser and there is nothing you can do.

People might try and find hacky ways to disable it, but my recommendation is not to.